# Php Change image on meta_value

Tags: php, wordpress, meta, posts

Im trying to make an image change based on which location is selected

the languages are a meta value of the posts.

here is my current code.
Any suggestions or corrections are greatly welcomed

```html
if( meta_value( 'germany' ) ) {
   $imageNumber = 001;
   echo '<img src="'home'.$imageNumber.'.jpg'">';
}
```

Comment: Any errors? What's this meta_value function?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code,

```
if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Your Meta Field Name', true ) == 'germany' ) {
   $imageNumber = 001;
   echo '<img src="home'.$imageNumber.'.jpg">';
}
```

Change Field name

Comment: this seems pretty close to what im looking for.
How ever i dont have a post id. i think


i dont know if this helps.


 'post_type'  => 'listings',
 'meta_key'  => 'location',
 'meta_value' => 'germany'

Answer (score -2):

You have syntax error. It should be `'<img src="home'.$imageNumber.'.jpg">'`.

Or use [interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) using double quotes and variable inside string:

```html
if( meta_value( 'germany' ) ) {
   $imageNumber = 001;
   echo "<img src='home{$imageNumber}.jpg'>";
}
```

Comment: seems like its not working still
Do i need to provide the php with the post type and meta key?

 'post_type'  => 'listings',
 'meta_key'  => 'location',